# When someone in my Upwork team makes a payment to an Upwork freelancer, where can I see the timestamp of the payment?

Tags: upwork

On https://www.upwork.com/nx/payments/reports/transaction-history and on the invoices, I can only see the date, but not the time in the day.

---

E.g., on the invoices obtained via https://www.upwork.com/nx/payments/reports/transaction-history, only the payment date is shown:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no way other than looking at the payment confirmation emails' timestamps:

[image]

Which means one cannot view the for timestamps for other people in one's Upwork team.